# Hide a form's client area (but let the title bar be visible) when mouse is not over the title bar

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, titlebar

I'm looking for a way to develop this:

[image: Heberger image]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_350415Explications.png))</sub>

When the mouse is over the form's title bar (rectange 1 on the picture) the form content (the rectangle 2) is visible & when the mouse is not over, it disappears but the rectangle 1 must remain visible!

How could i manage to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mouse events related to the non-client area of the forms (`WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`, `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE`, ...) that can be used for this purpose. But this is not simple, because they are not included in Windows Forms. To use this events, you should override `WndProc` of your form. Catching `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` event is somehow simple, but `WM_NCMOSUELEAVE` is a little tricky. Windows normally does not send mouse leave events to windows, unless they request it explicitly using `TrackMouseEvent` function.

Here is the complete code that does exactly what you want:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0xA0) // WM_NCMOUSEMOVE
        {
            TrackNcMouseLeave(this);
            ShowClientArea();
        }
        else if (m.Msg == 0x2A2) // WM_NCMOUSELEAVE
        {
            HideClientAreaIfPointerIsOut();
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        HideClientAreaIfPointerIsOut();
    }

    private int previouseHeight;

    private void ShowClientArea()
    {
        if (this.ClientSize.Height == 0)
            this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, previouseHeight);
    }

    private void HideClientAreaIfPointerIsOut()
    {
        if (this.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position))
            return;
        previouseHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;
        this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, 0);
    }

    public static void TrackNcMouseLeave(Control control)
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = new TRACKMOUSEEVENT();
        tme.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(tme);
        tme.dwFlags = 2 | 0x10; // TME_LEAVE | TME_NONCLIENT
        tme.hwndTrack = control.Handle;
        TrackMouseEvent(tme);
    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool TrackMouseEvent([In, Out] TRACKMOUSEEVENT lpEventTrack);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class TRACKMOUSEEVENT
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public IntPtr hwndTrack;
        public uint dwHoverTime;
    }
```

Put this code section in your form class, and that takes care of everything.

By overriding `WndProc` we are handling required mouse events. In `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` event, we call a method to inform the operating system that we are interested in `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE` event, and also we show the client area of the form (if not visible).
In `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE` event we hide the client area of the form (if the cursor is not on the form). Every time the `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE` event is called, all tracking events requested by `TrackMouseEvent` are canceled, so we must call the `TrackMouseEvent` function every time in `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`.

Be aware that maximizing the form is not considered in this code and you should handle it somehow.

Comment: Actually, i just have one little problem. The form disappears when the mouse is not on the header's form. I need the form to disappear when the mouse is not on the whole form.
The problem i have is i cannot click anywhere on the form since it automaticaly disappears before. I don't know if you see what i mean.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This behavior is according to what you described in your question. If it is not what you want, what exactly do you need? Please describe it, and I will explain how can you achieve that.

Comment: The form disappears if i'm not in Rectangle 1. I need to see the form if i'm in rectangle 2

Comment: @ArnaudAdigard: I modified the answer's code slightly to behave according to your needs. It works only if your form is **not** child of another form. Otherwise you need to change the cursor position before checking it in `HideClientAreaIfPointerIsOut()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you make a borderless form and use a custom control docked to the top as the title bar. Then it becomes as simple as changing the height of the form on MouseEnter and MouseLeave events!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that your Form BorderStyle is set on None, you can develop something based on the position of the mouse and the size of your rectangles, so you must use the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx) and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave.aspx) event as said *Digvijay*.

Here is my sample code:

```
    private void Rectangle1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myForm.Height = Rectangle1.Height + Rectangle2.Height;
    }

    private void Rectangle1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!myForm.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition))
        {
            myForm.Height = Rectangle1.Height;
        }
    }
```