# How to check if Mouse Click is in User Control without handling child control events?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have an User Control that host another controls like panel, chart controls.

Right now i have implemented the Header Panel control's MouseClick event to capture the mouse event, but i need to capture mouse click or mouseDown event on the whole user control area.

```
pnlHeader.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(pnlHeader_MouseUp);  //it is working 

//Not able to capture because child control coverup all area of the usercontrol.
this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MyCustomControl_MouseDown);
```

[image: Capture mouseclick event]

I went through this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359484/hide-a-forms-client-area-but-let-the-title-bar-be-visible-when-mouse-is-not-o), but it does not help me regarding mouse click or mouse down event.

*So what is correct and efficient way to capture user control mouse event??*

Any idea or suggestion with some reference code(if possible) will be accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way of bubbling events in WinForms like there is in HTML or in WPF

[How do I grab events from sub-controls on a user-control in a WinForms App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163104/how-do-i-grab-events-from-sub-controls-on-a-user-control-in-a-winforms-app)

So you will always need to add extra code.

Comment: +1 for nice suggestion, waiting for some better way otherwise i will implement this one and accept the answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to write this without so much code.  You could create your own `MouseDown` event handler in your user control that hides the existing handler and within directly hooks each control on your UserControl. For example, here's the MouseDown handler for a UserControl that contains a `Panel` and a `ListBox`:

```
// MouseDown event handler within UserControl
public new event MouseEventHandler MouseDown
{
    add 
    { 
        panel1.MouseDown += value;
        listBox1.MouseDown += value;
    }
    remove 
    { 
        panel1.MouseDown -= value;
        listBox1.MouseDown -= value;
    }
}
```

If you had more controls on your UserControl, you just add them to each section.

Your call in your parent WinForm must hook the `MouseDown` event for your UserControl like this:

```
myUserControl1.MouseDown += myUserControl1_MouseDown;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.OnUCMouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(UserControl1_OnUCMouseUp);
            panel1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseUp);
        }

        void UserControl1_OnUCMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("From userControl");
        }

        void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            InvokeMouseUp(this, e);
        }
        public event MouseEventHandler OnUCMouseUp;
        protected void InvokeMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.OnUCMouseUp != null)
                this.OnUCMouseUp(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, nice work but it is not desired way to implement. lots code lines added in this way..