# drag-and-drop between two user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, drag-and-drop

I have

1) a user control UC (consisting of radio button and textbox)

2) a form that contains more than one UC type control

I want to enable drag-and-drop between those UC controls (for example - dragging one control on to another would add text from the source control's constituent TextBox control to target control's constituent TextBox control)

What have i done so far:

1) I have set UC and it's constituent control AllowDrop = True

2) In container form i have written methods for UC control MouseDown, DragEnter and DragDrop events

The result:

Drag an drop works ONLY if i do drag and drop using parts of UC that do not contain constituent controls - that is, if i press mouse button on UC constituent TextBox control, UC MouseDown is not fired (if i press Mouse button on UC, but not on it's constituent TextBox or RadioButton controls, then UC MouseDown event is fired)

What i need:

I need drag-and-drop working regardless of whether the mouse button is pressed (released) on constituent control or not

Comment: Trying to reproduce the behavior of the Winforms designer isn't exactly simple.  It looks obvious, but it is complete counter to the way events work.  Having a problem with the user control's mouse event not getting fired is just the first issue you'll run into.  Sure, it doesn't work, the control that was clicked gets the event.  Never the user control.  Many, many more beyond that.  Have a look-see at this magazine article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Comment: It seems, that when i move mouse pointer on User control's constituent control, User control's DragLeave event is fired...

Comment: It seems, that when i move mouse pointer on User control's constituent control, User control's DragLeave event is fired... When i changed constituent control atribute AllowDrop to False I could successfully drop data on user control, by releasing mouse button on UC constituent control, but i still can not fire MouseDown event pressing mouse button on UC constituent control...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if Mouse Click is in User Control without handling child control events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028920/how-to-check-if-mouse-click-is-in-user-control-without-handling-child-control-ev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i needed to do was:

1) in user control - make an event delegate (MouseEventHandler, not EventHandler)

```
    public event MouseEventHandler eventName; //this one is accessible from container form
```

2) in user control - write a method for constituent control's MouseDown event that would wire constituent control's event to exposed event

```
    private void method_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //attached to constituent control's MouseDown event
    {
            if (this.eventName!= null) this.eventName(this, e);
    }
```

3) in container form, write a method for constituent control exposed event (eventName)

4) use User Control's DragDrop and DragEnter events (no need to use constituent control respective events)

5) AllowDrop atribute of Constituent controls should be False, otherwise moving mouse pointer on a constituent control triggers User Control's DragLeave event